# Merged Header Column for Radgrid without empty individual column headers?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

I'm attempting to make a merged header for a simple table that does not require individual column headers. Currently, I have the group column header successfully appearing, but below it, there is an empty column header for each column taking up unnecessary space.

```
<ColumnGroups>
                <telerik:GridColumnGroup HeaderText="Heatmap Status Counts" Name="StatusCounts" />
            </ColumnGroups>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Red" ColumnGroupName="StatusCounts" UniqueName="Red" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Orange" ColumnGroupName="StatusCounts" UniqueName="Orange" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Yellow" ColumnGroupName="StatusCounts" UniqueName="Yellow" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Green" ColumnGroupName="StatusCounts" UniqueName="Green" />
            </Columns>
```